# [MoveIt!] How to Use the Python Move Group Interface

Tags: ros, python, moveit, tutorial, moveit-commander

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use MoveIt! for pathfinding for a simple manipulator arm.
The [MoveIt! Setup Assistant](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_setup_assistant/html/doc/tutorial.html) and [Rviz Integration](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ros_visualization/html/doc/tutorial.html) tutorials were very helpful for the first usage of MoveIt! with the manipulator arm.

So far I can calculate paths between predefined poses using the Motion Planning extension. for Rviz

However, I now want to want to define a point in cartesian space. MoveIt! should then calculate a fitting manipulator pose itself and present a possible path from the current pose to the goal if there exists one.

I figured that this should be possible through the Move Group Interface of MoveIt! which I would then like to use with Python. This  [tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) coveres this problem, I think.
But I have no idea how to implement this for my own robot simulation.

Could someone explain me the steps that need to be done to transfer the tutorial on a different robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241305/%5Bmoveit!%5D-how-to-use-the-python-move-group-interface/) by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am not very skilled with python but I am using move_group with c++. For implementig that tutorial on your robot. You just need to change this command.

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm")
```

Instead of "left_arm" you should put name of your planning group which you specified in moveit_setup_assistant
Next important thing is to change desired goal to the real position which could your manipulator really reach.

```
pose_target = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
pose_target.orientation.w = 1.0
pose_target.position.x = 0.7
pose_target.position.y = -0.05
pose_target.position.z = 1.1
group.set_pose_target(pose_target)
```

Remember as it was mentioned in tutorial trajectory will be just planned and not executed

Whole code could be found here https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/blob/indigo-devel/pr2_moveit_tutorials/planning/scripts/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.py

When you will running code remember that your move_group should be running.

---

Originally posted by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) with karma: 110 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on 2016-08-09**:
Thanks for the answer.
Is my move_group running when I visualize the manipulator using Rviz?
So I would then only have to use:
$ rosrun myscript.py
To execute the script?

I get errors saying that the topic shut down unexpected, when I do this.

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2016-08-09**:
your move group should be running when you call

```
roslaunch robot_moveit_config demo.launch
```

"robot_moveit_config" is name of your package you setuped in setup_assistant. If it still does not work you can send me your "robot_moveit_config" and I could try to move robot on my own using python